# Bootstrap CSS Styling Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue with a dynamic form I am creating on my page.

I have a Row that contains 1 or more Divs that are 4 col in length. I would expect that after ever 3, it moves the next one down as it hits the 12 col limit.

Looking at the picture below, after we hit the first three fields I would think it would move the others down to their own row.

[image]

Here id the HMLT that my data is in. As you can see, each one is its own col within the row.

[image]

Is there something I am doing incorrectly with the way I have this formatted? Just not sure what else to try.

Comment: can you put your html in the question?

Comment: From past experience: the text input for the "Account Number" is slightly shorter (the height may be 1px smaller, or the margin/padding-bottom is less) and causes this... but without real code (HTML and CSS) to see, it's almost impossible to tell

Comment: Thanks  @JosephMarikle - I do have access to the code that generates the page but a little unsure what you mean regarding `modulus operator`

Comment: @SBB Sorry.  I deleted my comment.  Was second guessing myself.  Anyway, it *should be working* based on [this part of the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping), but it isn't as you can see in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24doudo0/).  (Other devs, please feel free to use that fiddle if you can think of a solution or workaround).

Comment: @SBB As far as modulo is concerned (represented by `%` usually), it's the remainder after division of two variables.  So `5 % 3` would be 2.  You can use it like this: `if(count % 3 == 0)`.  It means if the current count divided by 3 results in a 0 remainder (e.g. 3, 6, 9, ...) return true.  You can offset it by testing for the next number in the sequence if necessary too: `if(count % 3 == 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is proper to create a `.row` for every row on the page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not necessarily.  Bootstrap columns are supposed to wrap to the next line when the total width exceeds 12.

Comment: I've had trouble with column wrapping before too, but I always figured it wasn't supported.  It appears that it is (supposed to be): http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping

Comment: @alexw I think you're right. I guess since they named the class `.row`, I automatically assumed that they meant to use it that way and not allow for multiple levels in one row..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday, what I found is that the container should have the col length specified in order to fix the problem.

Also I found useful to add additional divs in order to fix better the length of the fields.

My example:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          your label data
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          your input data
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          your label data
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          your input data
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Do they have to be in their own rows? I have 1 container, 1 row and then an unknown numbers of Col-4 's that can show up.

Comment: They don't have to be in their own but sometimes for better styling you will end up adding more divs. You can have one div which take col-12 and then the inside divs will fill the space

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your screenshot, but it looks like you have the whole thing (rows, columns, and some form groups) inside of a `span` element.  Try using a `div` instead.

Comment: That was a good guess; I was hopeful. Unfortunately it still didnt fix it :/

Comment: Hmm.  Can you post the actual source HTML of the page? (Not the console log, because that will not reveal missing tags).

Answer (score 0):

The problem: http://jsfiddle.net/24doudo0/

This seems to be an issue with how bootstrap handles [grid wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).  It doesn't handle as nicely as we would like.  I can think of two solutions to this problem.  The first is to insert rows after every third column when you loop over them in the backend.  For that you can use the modulus operator.  I don't know what backend language you are using, but I'll illustrate this approach using PHP because I'm lazy.

Lets assume you have an array of input names that you want to loop over and create columns for each.

```
<div class="row">
    <? foreach ($inputs as $count => $name) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="<?=$name?>">
    </div>
        <? if (($count + 1) % 3 == 0) : // $count is 0 based.  We need an index that starts at 1 so that we don't trigger a new row on the first loop (0 / 3 = 0 which is a remainder of 0) ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <? endif; ?>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The other solutions is a CSS based one.  Pretty simple but is CSS3 only, so it won't work in IE 8 or less.  This approach just clears the float after every third column.  Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/j0dtng4t/

```
[class*="col-"] {
    background: #C55;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
}

[class*="col-"]:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. I am using Javascript as my code for this piece. I have about 15 optional fields that I allow a user to fill out. I then just check what options to show based on the group they are in. Here is a screenshot to show one of the fields. http://oi60.tinypic.com/55jkm8.jpg

Comment: The same principle applies.  Javascript uses the `%` operator for modulus operations.  I don't see an index that's being incremented, but you could easily add one.  A simple `var count = 1`; and `count++;` at the end of your loop would work.  When you make your comparison, you can add a class or do something like `table += '</div><div class="row">';`

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are at least other 2 alternative solutions you can consider without adding row divs.

The first is adding heights to all the `.col*` elements , in this way they'll get ordered progressively and stack when they don't fit next to each other.[(checkout the pen)](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/VYyEEM).

The [second](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/VYyEgr) is using  display flex on the div containing the `.col*` elements; it's not a bootstrap feature but it seems to suite your situation quite well.

In the pens I made I modified the `col-*` selectors but I suggest you use a new selector so not to mess with Bootstrap's grid style.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion on how floats work especially in a bootstrap grid.

Here is a simple bit of code that demonstrates how floats work

```css
.container-fluid {min-width:638px;}
.container-fluid p{margin:0;font-size:1.2rem}
[class*="col-"] {
    background: #C55;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 1 <p>we work because we are the same height</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 2 <p>we work because we are the same height</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 3 <p>we work because we are the same height</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 1
         </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 2 <p>I'm tall, but my buddies aren't</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          column 2 <p>I'm  tall but because Fred is too wide he goes to the far left to fit</p>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          column 3
        </div>    
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          Fred column 1
        </div>    
    </div>
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4">
          inputs are taller than select
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
                    inputs are taller than select
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          selects are smaller
        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="text" placeholder="i'm too tall" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="text" placeholder="i'm too tall" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <select><option>i'm shorter</option></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">that's why i'm column 3</div>
    
   </div>
 </div>
```